# "which is no more"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Beyond its farther edge the Alppain glow burned blue just over the horizon.
>
> “But that terrible blue glare on the opposite side is exactly like the eye of fate. It accuses us, and demands what we have made of our life, which is no more. At the same time, it is grand and joyful…”
> *– A Voyage to Arcturus*

Here the character says the blue glare of Alppain “demands what we have made of our life, which is no more.” I do not quite understand this sentence. Here *demand* may mean "ask, inquire", and *make of* may mean "understand, interpret". But even if these are partly clear, I cannot figure out the relative clause *which is no more*.

What does this sentence actually mean? Can someone paraphrase it for me?

Comment: [Demand](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/demand) *- to claim as just or due*. I don't know the full context, but it looks like "the blue glare of Alppain" (whoever or whatever that is) is laying claim to (exacting in payment/tribute) "what we have made of our life". And furthermore, that "we" are going to be killed shortly, since our life is "no more" (i.e. - "has ended").

Comment: to be no more = to have ceased to be http://www.thefreedictionary.com/To+be+no+more

Comment: According to the author, "our life"—that is the life of the narrator and whoever else the narrator has been talking about—is no more. That's about as straightforward as the usage gets.

Answer (score 1):

From the context, I would suggest that whoever or whatever the 'blue glare' is, it is demanding an account, explanation or justification of our lives.  Demand may be sort of short-hand for 'demand to know'.

As FumbleFingers says, 'which is no more' refers to our life having ended.